# Making Angular2 router work with multiple /'s

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

A user can come to my SPA from many different urls.

```
/page1
/page2
/page3
```

The web server I'm hosting this app of of is being protected. and a user case has come up where for some of the pages, we want to turn off protection.

So I want something like /p/page1 `/p/page2`, will be protected pages. And if a user tries to access them without being logged, they'll be redirected to login page.  Else if there trying to access /u/page3, they will be able to load the page.  After the page is loaded of course the user would be able to access any of the spa pages, and at that time, I'll be checking if there logged  in when making service requests.  But I'd like to shave some time and make things quick by having a protection layer on the web server.

The Problem is that the angular trouters don't seem to work with a path of /p/page1.  And I've also tried to have /p with children page1 and page2, nothing seems to work.  How can I set a route where the first directory isn't associated with any component, it's just there for organization purposes.

EDIT:

My router

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', children:[
    { path: 'u', children:[
      { path: 'landing', component: Landing } 
    ]},
    { path: 'p', component: Enroll, children:[
      { path: 'enroll', component: Enroll },
      { path: 'manage', component: Manage },
    ]}
  ] }
];

/u/landing will not work.
/p/enroll will not work.
/p will work though.
```

auto generated html, atleast when including js files, the js files aren't properly being fetched.

```
<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
  <!--#include file="../assets/test.html"-->
  <div class="hp-main-container">
    <!--<enroll-header>Header Loading...</enroll-header>-->
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>

</body>
```

ERROR:

```
 https://my.site.com:80/p/main.bundle.js 404 ()
```

The Fix:

```
<base href="./">
```

Changed to

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem to be honest. Maybe you could share your current routing configuration...

Comment: Updated with my router, these routes are being found, i'm not getting a not found in router error, but the component doesn't even try to load.

Comment: Are you accessing the routes using angular routers functions and directives or just typing them in the address bar to test? If it's the latter it could simply be a web server configuration issue depending on your setup, where the server isn't rewriting urls that include a slash. Your routes look fine to me at first glance.

Comment: I am writing the urls in to test, and I'm using ng serve, at least for development.  As part of angular-cli.

Comment: I have no problems loading index.html, but <app-root>Loading...</app-root> never loads.

Comment: Does the Enroll component template include a <router-outlet>?

Comment: OH, it's looking for my javascript files in /p now, how do I get it to stop doing that, the index.html file is dynamically created from ng build

Comment: Are you including the <base href="/"> in your index.html head?

Comment: Yes,   <base href="./"> is in my <head>

Comment: There's your error. Compare your <base> with mine, there should not be a period in there denoting a relative URL...